# Multiple JS Scroll CONTENT

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

http://jsfiddle.net/s5mgX/184/

How can I write this more efficiently where that

1) I can have about 50 scroll content `DIV` like in the example above on 1 page but not having the repeat the entire JS implementation

Answer (score 1):

I updated your fiddle. Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/s5mgX/198/ Anyway, you needed to put the links and content in the same div so they're siblings, then use class instead of id & use a siblings('.content') instead of $('#content')